# pop up autogenerate without borders

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow

I have an automatic generated pop up window like the one below, and i am thinking if it is possible to have the same pop up without the bar with the url and the buttons of minimize, restore down/up, and close.

```
<html>

<body onLoad="setTimeout('window.open(\'Desert.jpg\',\'popup\',\'toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,copyhistory=0,width=375,height=350, top=100, left=150\')',5000)">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.open) reference, which has almost all that you need to know about `window.open`, the following are the properties you are interested in:

> ## Toolbar and chrome features
>
> [...]
>
> ### location
>
> If this feature is on, then the new secondary window renders the Location bar in Mozilla-based browsers. MSIE 5+ and Opera
> 7.x renders the Address Bar. Mozilla and Firefox users can force new windows to always render the location bar by setting
> dom.disable_window_open_feature.location to true in about:config or in
> their user.js file.
>
> Supported in: Internet Explorer 5+, Netscape 6.x, Netscape 7.x,
> Mozilla 1.x, Firefox 1.x, Opera 6+
>
> [...]
>
> ## Window functionality features
>
> [...]
>
> ### dialog
>
> MenuSystemCommands.pngThe dialog feature removes all icons (restore, minimize, maximize) from the window's titlebar, leaving only
> the close button. Mozilla 1.2+ and Netscape 7.1 will render the other
> menu system commands (in FF 1.0 and in NS 7.0x, the command system
> menu is not identified with the Firefox/NS 7.0x icon on the left end
> of the titlebar: that's probably a bug. You can access the command
> system menu with a right-click on the titlebar). Dialog windows are
> windows which have no minimize system command icon and no
> maximize/restore down system command icon on the titlebar nor in
> correspondent menu item in the command system menu. They are said to
> be dialog because their normal, usual purpose is to only notify info
> and to be dismissed, closed. On Mac systems, dialog windows have a
> different window border and they may get turned into a sheet.
>
> Supported in: Netscape 6.x, Netscape 7.x, Mozilla 1.x, Firefox 1.x
>
> [...]
>
> ## Features requiring privileges
>
> The following features require the UniversalBrowserWrite privilege,
> otherwise they will be ignored. Chrome scripts have this privilege
> automatically, others have to request it from the PrivilegeManager.
>
> [...]
>
> ### close
>
> When set to no or 0, this feature removes the system close command icon and system close menu item. It will only work for dialog
> windows (dialog feature set). close=no will override minimizable=yes.
> Mozilla and Firefox users can force new windows to always have a close
> button by setting dom.disable_window_open_feature.close to true in
> about:config or in their user.js file.
>
> Supported in: Netscape 6.x, Netscape 7.x, Mozilla 1.x, Firefox 1.x